# GeckoFx 45 How to disable the Timeout MsgBox "Alert"

Tags: timeout, webbrowser-control, alert, geckofx, msgbox

When I use GeckoFx-45 I sometimes get a MsgBox popup named "Alert" with the text: 
The operation timed out when attempting to contact xxx

I can't find a option to disabled this alert.
It needs to manually clicked to resume the Application.

Does anybody knows how to disabled the Timeout Alert at GeckoFx-45 Browser?

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried adding a handler for the `NavigationError` event?

Comment: I added a window kill function with a timer every 5 seconds to check if the popup is open and if it is opened kill it.